# Optional generic parameter - Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I've created function to accept generic type in parameter, but it's optional.

```
func addTag<T>(value: String, data: T? = nil) {

}
```

When I tried to invoke this function by passing data, it's working fine.

```
taggingView.addTag(value: "Value2", data: myInfo)
```

But without data, it throws `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

```
taggingView.addTag(value: "value1")
```

Its to be understood that Swift compiler unable to infer T type. But I need to keep it as Optional. Any solution to this?

Comment: Infer as what? `Int?`, `Double?`, `String?`, `?`– the compiler does not guess.

Comment: Yes, Compiler can't guess it. Any way to assign default value, from that also compiler can infer?

Comment: @KiranJasvanee, you may try creating non-generic `addTag(value:)` function, which will call this generic one with some hardcoded type T.

Comment: Define two functions: A generic `func addTag<T>(value: String, data: T)` or `func addTag<T>(value: String, data: T?)`  and a non-generic `func addTag(value: String)`

Comment: @MartinR creating two different functions working fine. Thanks for the alternate solution. Still I'm looking for assigning a default value for generic parameter.